# VBA - Overwrite XML property of MSXML2.DOMDocument

Tags: xml, vba

I have the following subroutine where I want to loop through an XML document and overwrite specific nodes. There is a Range in Excel where I've already constructed the xml string exactly as I need it. Is there an easy way to just set the xml property the same way I can overwrite the text property? I tried to go the MSXML route to make it easier to traverse the dom but in this case it might just be easier to traverse the text file line by line unless someone knows an easy way to do this. I realize I could loop through the child nodes and individually set the `<V>` tags but that has other challenges and it seems more effort then it is worth.

```
Sub TestXML()
Dim path As String: path = Range("FilePath")
Dim XDoc As Object, root As Object

Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load (path)

Dim Nodes As Variant: Set Nodes = XDoc.SelectNodes("//P")
Dim NodeLength As Integer: NodeLength = Nodes.Length

For Each listnode In Nodes
  //This works but does not format correctly
  listnode.text = "<P><D>Bob</D><V>Lob</V><V>law</V></P>"
  //This throws a Run-time error 450 wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
  listnode.xml = "<P><D>Bob</D><V>Lob</V><V>law</V></P>"
Next listnode

XDoc.Save Range("FilePath")
Set XDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696312/62576

Comment: Hi Ken, I am aware that I can access the child elements with childNodes.item().  My question is can I overwrite the parent node without having to loop through and update every child node.  In this case I have about 50 child nodes in the <V> tags that are already formatted properly in Excel.

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well.